# Set title property if the data returned from binding is true in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

i'm a newbie in vuejs, my question is how to set title by a value returned from specific method if this value is true, here's my code:

```
<td
  v-bind="value = getName(id)"
  :title="value.age"
>
  {{value.name}}
</td>
```

But this code doesn't work if the method returned `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a computed property.

```
computed: {
  title: function() {
     return this.value ? this.value.age : ''
  }
}
```

In this way we are ensuring that `this.value` is not `undefined` and we use the `age` off of the object, otherwise an empty string (or you can replace it with whatever you want. Now just use that as the title property:

```
:title="title"
```